# What computer languages do Linux-based OSes use?

Tags: kernel, programming, design

What programming languages are used to make/create Linux-based Operating Systems?

Comment: The kernel is written in C, as well as most system libraries used in most distros.

Comment: Is that all? I thought making/creating linux will will be using C,C++ and other applications?

Comment: Depends on what. He is talking about kernel, the core part. Other stuff is written in all languages imaginable I think.

Comment: Most common are C, C++, Perl, Python, PHP and more recently Ruby. C is actually everywhere, as indeed the kernel is written in C. Perl and Python (2.6/2.7 mostly these days) are shipped with almost every distro. Some major components like installer scripts are written in Python or Perl, sometimes using both.

Comment: And don't forget all the other stuff, most importantly Javascript, which is now the recommended language of the Gnome platform.

Answer (score 15):

- Linux (the kernel) is essentially written in C with a little of assembly code.
- The lower layer of userland, usually GNU (glibc and other libraries plus standard core commands) are almost exclusively written in C and shell scripting.
- The remaining of the Gnu/Linux distributions userland is written in any language developers decide to use (still a lot of C and shell but also C++, python, perl, javascript, java, C#, golang, whatever ...)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the following link has the answer you're looking for: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=705754

To paraphrase my favorite answers there:

1. [Linux](https://www.openhub.net/p/linux/analyses/latest/languages_summary), the kernel, is mostly written in **C** and a little bit of **Assembly**.
2. Toolkits and frameworks used to develop the graphical interface (e.g. [GTK+](https://www.openhub.net/p/gtk/analyses/latest/languages_summary), [Qt](https://www.openhub.net/p/qt), [GNOME](https://www.openhub.net/p/gnome/analyses/latest/languages_summary), [KDE](https://www.openhub.net/p/kde/analyses/latest/languages_summary), [Unity](https://www.openhub.net/p/ubuntu-unity/analyses/latest/languages_summary)) are written mostly in **C** and **C++**.
3. Utilities and applications (i.e. programs) that come bundled with the Operating System are usually written in **Java**, **Python**, **C**, **C++** and even **C#**.