# Is Haskell a Linux Dependency

Tags: dependencies, source-code, haskell

I just thought to make the situation simple & attempt to figure out if Linux depends on Haskell. I don't use Haskell, & it seems that most of the columns published talk about how to install haskell & meet dependencies for haskell programers.

I'd rather not use Haskell, not actually.

I used to actually program BASIC (my first programmers guide was a gift when it's context I was in Kindergarten). I don't want to go back to that level, not actually, & even though I have actually read the suggested intention of "BrainFuck", that seems sort of dichotomic within the context. If that suggested the same thing & was named "BrainStorm", I wouldn't be bothered.

I am interested in the source code contexts that make Linux functional. I just have not actually found documented suggestion that Linux depends on Haskell, not actually. I thought to ask to make sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What computer languages do Linux-based OSes use?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/324250/what-computer-languages-do-linux-based-oses-use)

Comment: The Linux kernel does not use Haskell in any way.

Answer (score 1):

> I just thought to make the situation simple & attempt to figure out if Linux depends on Haskell.

"Linux", properly considered, is just the operating system kernel. I can guarantee that isn't one ioata of Haskell in the Linux source code, nor in the GCC toolchain plus the few other utilities that are needed to build Linux. So there isn't even a build dependency on Haskell, let alone a runtime dependency.

Haskell is 100% optional.